# How to write to a file without deleting privious existing data

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I am try to write data to a text file. I am using this code:

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
writer.write("something");
}
```

But while the program is running, the file is overwriting the exist data that are already found in the text file. How can i write new data lines to the same text file without overwriting it ? Is there any easy and simple way to write it?

Comment: the page you provide it does not work with me because of that i posted my question here @ekuusela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(
          Paths.get("filename.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
          StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
          StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
    writer.write("something");
}
```

The open options are a varargs list, and default to new file creation.

BTW FileWriter uses the platform encoding, so you where right to not use that class. It is not portable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use [FileWriter(File file, Boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.